# Ubuntu 18 and MySql 8. Out of memory

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I recently installed Ubuntu 18 server with MySQL 8 and Apache inside a VMware virtual machine with 8GB of RAM and 500Gb of HD.

I did not configure much inside `my.cnf`, except:

```
innodb_dedicated_server = 1
```

Everything runs fine, except that every now and then Mysql service reboots. 
Inside `/var/log/syslog` I can see:

> Out of memory: Kill process 6880 (mysqld) score 934 or sacrifice child

I tried removing that line (and so bringing back the default config) and that error did not appear anymore.

Do you think it's a bug of Mysql 8 or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This is called [OOM Killer (Out Of Memory Killer)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) it is called when you reach 100% use of memory to select and kill processes to gain back some memory for system use.

Comment: thanks, I did get it was a memory problem, what I don't know is how to solve it and why it happened :-)

Answer (score 0):

You run out of memory.

The option you configured is for automatic setup of memory settings for a *dedicated mysql server* - meaning: a server that does nothing but mysql. No Apache, no GUI, etc. No wonder it uses a lot of memory. Disable this option, if you want to run other services on this machine and configure the memory usage manually..

To save memory, you can reduce the number of concurrent threads or the amount of memory per thread.

Using myISAM an InnoDB-Engine uses more RAM, so if you can forgo one of these, disable it in your config.

mysqltuner can be a useful tool here, too. It gives you information like this:

```
[--] Total buffers: 432.0M global + 66.6M per thread (50 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 3.7G (23% of installed RAM)
```

Production Database Servers need RAM. Lot's of RAM.

Comment: Thanks! It actually is a dedicated server..the only thing more is apache which does not seems to use much memory (but I might be wrong).I thought about using innodb_dedicated_server because of that. I tried to use mysqltuner but it looks like it does not yet support mysql 8.15. Removing innodb_dedicated_server did solve all the problems. I do not see any other problem for now except it's not very tuned. I have 8Gb and it uses just 3.